# Converting an object literal to a sorted Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an object literal, where the values of its key are more objects, and one of the keys of the inner objects is named "rank" - and has an floating point value. I want to convert the object literal to an array of the inner objects,  sorted by the value of "rank".

**Input Object:**

```
{
452:{
     bla:123,
     dff:233,
     rank:2
  },
234:{
     bla:123,
     dff:233,
     rank:1
  }
```

}

**Output Array:**

```
[
 { bla:123, dff:233, rank:1},
 { bla:123, dff:233, rank:2 }
]
```

Comment: Post some code, preferrably the object in question.

Comment: We need to see the object literal code that you want to convert to an array.  Show us the code.

Comment: Foks will be happy to help if you show the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Example:

```
var data = {
    foo: {
        rank: 5
    },
    bar: {
        rank: 2
    },
    baz: {
        rank: 8
    }
};
```

Javascript:

```
var mappedHash = Object.keys( data ).sort(function( a, b ) {
    return data[ a ].rank - data[ b ].rank;
}).map(function( sortedKey ) {
    return data[ sortedKey ];
});
```

That would first `sort` the inner objects by the value of `obj.rank` and after that `map` the containing objects into an *Array*.

**Result**: `[{rank: 2}, {rank: 5}, {rank: 8}]`

---

Reference: [`Object.keys`](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys&ei=Ele9UP-5F8jE4gTo6oD4Bw&usg=AFQjCNGS2XnTfEoWXTgd6aYQgHSRp6_Avg), [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort&ei=Nle9UIyFJ8f44QST4IGICA&usg=AFQjCNHjOWoFr-M96-uu3nqVgokfuhQr7A), [`Array.prototype.map`](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map&ei=4Ve9UJvEEMjE4gTo6oD4Bw&usg=AFQjCNFsASIf8Dn00uRKdgprYm9Y6rymaA)

---

<sup>The above code contains ECMAscript 262 edition 5 code, which is available in all modern browsers. If you want to support legacy browsers as well, you need to include one of the various ES5-Shim libraries.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over your object's properties, pushing the inner objects into an array, and then sort the array with a custom sort function:

```
var inputObject = {}, // your object here
    arr = [];

for (var k in inputObject)
    arr.push(inputObject[k]);

arr.sort(function(a,b) { return a.rank - b.rank; });
```

Comment: I am trying to reply to the user nnnnnn using the "@" symbol as instructed in the help section.  It is not working.  I have had this issue in other posts as well -- using my Mac or PC. It simply does not show up when I use the "@" sign before the user name.  Where should I post a question like this?

Comment: At any rate,  For nnnnnn, what does `a.rank - b.rank` do in the sort method of the array?  Thanks.

Comment: @Chris22 [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) lets you pass a function that will be called whenever comparison between two elements in the array is needed - `a` and `b` being the two elements. The comparison function needs to return a positive number if `a` should come after `b` in the sorted results, a negative number if `a` should come before `b`, and `0` if `a` and `b` are equal for sort purposes. In this case the elements are objects that have a numeric `rank` property, so `a.rank - b.rank` returns an appropriate value.

Comment: @Chris22 - Regarding your difficulty with the `@` sign, you don't need to use it with the username of the person whose answer or question you are commenting under, they'll see your comment without it.

Comment: Thanks for both explanation, nnnnnn.  I understand both much better now.  :)