# Convert javascript object to array with specific order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How can I convert a javascript object into an array of objects? Array elements must be ordered by the `index` property in the original object:

**Input**:

```
var o = {
  "0gfbpa1508024708952": {
    title: "hi daughter",
    index: 3
  },
  "b8tl5k1508024741100": {
    title: "hi dad",
    index: 0
  },
  "cxr9x1508024697320": {
    title: "hi son",
    index: 2
  },
  "qua2802469732": {
    title: "hi cousin",
    index: 9007199254740991
  },
  "tck80i1508024731561": {
    title: "hi mom",
    index: 1
  }
};
```

**Output**:

```
[
  {id: "b8tl5k1508024741100", title: "hi dad"},        // array index 0
  {id: "tck80i1508024731561", title: "hi mom"},        // array index 1
  {id: "cxr9x1508024697320", title: "hi son"},         // array index 2
  {id: "0gfbpa1508024708952", title: "hi daughter"},   // array index 3
  {id: "qua2802469732", title: "hi cousin"}            // array index 4
]
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694883/converting-an-object-literal-to-a-sorted-array) only helps with the ordering/sorting of the array. It doesn't explain how to (1) transform the object key into the array object `id` property and (2) how to remove the `index` key from the array. There is transformation going on here, not just ordering/sorting based on object keys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting an object literal to a sorted Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694883/converting-an-object-literal-to-a-sorted-array)

Answer (score 1):

```
let o = {
  "0gfbpa1508024708952": {
    title: "hi daughter",
    index: 3
  },
  "b8tl5k1508024741100": {
    title: "hi dad",
    index: 0
  },
  "cxr9x1508024697320": {
    title: "hi son",
    index: 2
  },
  "qua2802469732": {
    title: "hi cousin",
    index: 9007199254740991
  },
  "tck80i1508024731561": {
    title: "hi mom",
    index: 1
  }
},
arr = [];


for (let k in o) {
  let tmp = o[k];
  tmp.id = k;
  arr.push(tmp);
}
arr.sort(function(a,b) { return a.index - b.index; });

for (let k in arr)
  delete arr[k].index;
```